# Can two iPhone apps built from the same code use different iTunesArtwork (full version & lite/free version)?

Tags: iphone, plist, itunes-store

I am currently building a full and a lite/free version of an iPhone app from the same source (along the lines of [Creating Lite Versions of iPhone Games / Apps](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2098)). This works great.

The only thing I cannot figure out is how to have two different iTunesArtwork files included in the respective build (e.g. one with a "lite" stamp on it, one without).

I read [App Icons on iPad and iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) on Apple's page but they don't say what to do with iTunesArtwork. I did include different "Icon.png" etc. files in the two different *.plists I have and this works as expected. But what about iTunesArtwork?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are asking about the artwork that is submitted to iTunes Connect.

Comment: Kind of, I guess :) I sent an "ipa" archive via e-mail to someone. That archive (seemed to) contain the iTunesArtwork file.

Comment: What is the "iTunesArtwork" file?

Comment: The 512x512 icon to be displayed in iTunes (also while AdHoc testing). It's a *.png file without the png ending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not required to embed the 512x512 artwork into your bundle. In iTunes Connect you will be able to upload the 512x512 file and you will be able to upload screen captures for the two different apps.

Comment: OK, that is good. But for some reason the (wrong) icon appears for the lite version while ad hoc testing. This irritates my testers... Any thoughts?

Comment: I assume you are doing different targets for the different versions. These different targets can have different info.plist files and can therefore have different Icon file settings. Actually, if you reread the very first link in your question, he tells you exactly how to have different icons for the different targets.

Comment: The thing is that the 512x512 iTunesArtwork file is *not* referenced in the *.plist file(s). At least this is my understanding (especially after reading the second link). It does work for the icons though (smaller versions of iTunesArtwork to be displayed on the device, not in iTunes).

Comment: For distribution (to iTunes AppStore) I can upload the 512x512 image separately, so this is no concern. It's only about ad hoc testing... I am marking this as answer. Thx!

Comment: Thanks. In Xcode4 you can look under the "Build Phases" setting for the target. Then look under "Copy Bundle Resources" section. Here is where you can replace one actual icon file with another. Maybe this will get you to where you want to be.

Answer (score 1):

In XCode 4 you can create a group where you put your target specific files and assign them the correct target membership in the identity inspector.
Thus you have always the correct iTunesArtwork in your .ipa file.

This worked for me like a charm.

Hope it helps.